# How to apply custom "css" and "js" files to all admins in only one app efficiently?

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, django-admin

I have custom `css` and `js` files, `admin.py` and overridden [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) located in `templates/admin/app1/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1
 |              |-css
 |              |  └-custom.css # Here
 |              └-js
 |                 └-custom.js # Here
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py # Here
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-app1
          └-base.html # Here
```

First, I set the custom `css` and `js` files to `css` and `js` respectively in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition) in all admins `Person`, `Animal` and `Food` in `app1` as shown below, then I can apply them to all admins `Person`, `Animal` and `Food` in only `app1`:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person, Animal, Food

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('core/admin/app1/css/custom.css',) # Here
        }
        js = ('core/admin/app1/js/custom.js',) # Here

@admin.register(Animal)
class AnimalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('core/admin/app1/css/custom.css',) # Here
        }
        js = ('core/admin/app1/js/custom.js',) # Here

@admin.register(Food)
class FoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('core/admin/app1/css/custom.css',) # Here
        }
        js = ('core/admin/app1/js/custom.js',) # Here
```

But, the solution above is not efficient so instead I set them after `<link ... "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">` in `base.html` as shown below but the solution below doesn't work:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/admin/app1/css/custom.css" %}"> {# Here #}
<script src="{% static 'core/admin/app1/js/custom.js' %}" defer></script> {# Here #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/css/dark_mode.css" %}">
# ...
```

So, I put `base.html` in `templates/admin/` as shown below, then the solution above works but the custom `css` and `js` files are applied to all admins in all apps:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1
 |              |-css
 |              |  └-custom.css
 |              └-js
 |                 └-custom.js
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

So, how can I apply the custom `css` and `js` files to all admins `Person`, `Animal` and `Food` in only `app1` efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use comment.

> When I have some custom static files, I follow the following process.

## 1. setting static folder

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # add
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core', 'static' ....)
]
....
```

## 2. check router.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 
# add
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

## 3. check settings.py

```py
# add
STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

## 4. run command

```bash
python manage.py collectstatic
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/4.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: Do you mean this?